# Figuring out the formula for two objects in 3d space

Tags: c++, math, 3d, formula, space

I am trying to figure out the formula to get the distance between two objects in 3d space. So far, the answers are wrong when I run the program:

```
float Distance3D(const float & object1X , 
             const float & object1Y ,
             const float & object1Z , 
             const float & object2X , 
             const float & object2Y ,
             const float & object2Z )
{
    float x = pow ((object2X - object1X),2);// for x
    float y = pow ((object2Y - object1Y),2);// for y
    float z = pow ((object2Z - object1Z),2);// for z
    float objectDistance = 0.0f;

    objectDistance = sqrt(object2X*object1X + object2Y*object1Y + object2Z*object1Z);
    cout << objectDistance << endl;

    return objectDistance;
}
```

Comment: You start correctly, but then abandon it completely. Why did you calculate `x`, `y` and `z` if you never use them in the later code? You correctly calculated `x`, `y` and `z`. Now continue to work with `x`, `y` and `z` to get the distance.

Comment: I would like to voice my disapproval of your math teachers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the Euclidean distance between 2 points in 3D space your code should look more like

```
objectDistance = sqrt((object2X-object1X)*(object2X-object1X) + 
                      (object2Y-object1Y)*(object2Y-object1Y) + 
                      (object2Z-object1Z)*(object2Z-object1Z));
```

or more simply using your squared distance variables `x,y,z` :

```
objectDistance = sqrt(x + y + z);
```

Comment: The `x`, `y` and `z` are already squared. You don't need to square them again.

Comment: @AndreyT Thanks for pointing that out. I only added them after the question was edited

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are interested strictly in distance of two *points* in a 3-D space, [Gilbert-Johnson-Keerthi distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert-Johnson-Keerthi_distance_algorithm) is what you might be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Distance in 3D space is usually found using the [Pythagorean Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).

The formula for this is

```
d^2=(x0-x1)^2+(y0-y1)^2+(z0-z1)^2
```

where `d` is the distance between the points.

Using this formula, your code should look like

```
float Distance3D(const float & object1X , 
             const float & object1Y ,
             const float & object1Z , 
             const float & object2X , 
             const float & object2Y ,
             const float & object2Z )
{
    float delta_x = pow (object2X - object1X,2);// for x
    float delta_y = pow (object2Y - object1Y,2);// for y
    float delta_z = pow (object2Z - object1Z,2);// for z
    float objectDistance = 0.0f;

    objectDistance = sqrt(delta_x*delta_x + delta_y*delta_y + delta_z*delta_z);
    cout << objectDistance << endl;

    return objectDistance;
}
```

Interestingly, for high-dimensional data the usefulness of this metric declines and the [Manhatten distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) can become a preferable metric. A paper entitled "On the Surprising Behavior of Distance Metrics in High Dimensional Space" by [Aggarwal (2001)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.23.7409) has been wrote about this.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is incorrect; take a look at [the 2D distance formula](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm), then extend it to 3D.

Also note the similarities to the formula for getting 2D/3D vector length.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the square root of the square of the difference of each component. See [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)